# How do I establish media query hierarchy in CSS3?

Tags: css, media-queries

I encountered a strange problem while working on a test page.  We're working on coming up with a new style for the website but it needs to work for mobile so I went with media queries.

Note: fmu is a ul for footer menu and fml is a li for footer menu

```css
   @media screen and (min-width: 640px)
            {
    fmu fml
    {
     font-size: 1rem;
     padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    }
    fmu fml fmu
    {
     position: absolute;
    }
            }
   @media only screen and (min-device-width : 719px) and (max-device-width : 721px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (orientation : portrait)
   { 
    fmu {position: static;}
    fmu fml
    {
     font-size: 1rem;
     padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem;
     width: 100%
    }
    fmu > fml > fmu
    {
     font-size: 1rem;
     padding: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.25rem;
     width: 100%
     position: relative !important;
     background-color: royalblue;
    }
    fmu fml a, fmu fml fmu fml a
    {
     width: 100%
    }
   }
```

On my phone (Galaxy S3) with the default browser both of these queries are run or applied or whatever when the phone is in portrait mode.  Some values are different from one to the next, but the position: absolute in fmu fml fmu for the first query doesn't seem to be able to be overridden.

I think this is some kind of hierarchy issue with the queries.  I tried being more specific with the > and I tried using !important but the position:relative just won't take hold.  I also tried reversing the order of these queries.  Is there a way to make the second query here absolutely override anything that the first one has if they BOTH get applied to something?  Via some other tests I am able to verify that my phone while in portrait does indeed read both queries.

Comment: There is a missing semicolon after `width: 100%`—is that your problem?

Comment: Both media queries will take effect as the S3 has a screen size of 720x1280. The first media query states that if the screen is larger than 640px in width the CSS should take effect. Perhaps you mean `max-width:640px;`?